# show USER TASKS (webPart)

Tags: 2013, web-part, tasks, task-list

I am new here as well as new to SharePoint 2013.

I wanted to use the USER TASKS webpart to show the user's tasks on the page,
instead of the user having to navigate to `MySite > Tasks`

I found UserTasks in Social Collaboration.

Some examples show the User Task being in Content Rollup but is not there.

Any advise?!

[image: ContentRollup]

This is my idea behind this all:

The main page, should show a small section (whoever is logged in as) of what his/her current project tasks are... and then if they want, they can navigate to the main project page to see everything else.

That is why I used the "user tasks" webpart in thinking it would do that but it does not ... it only shows tasks if you create Workflow tasks - of which I have not much idea about!

Comment: "There are no items to show in this view" is being displayed when adding the User Tasks webpart.

Comment: Go to "Workflow Tasks" list and add task and assign it to current user. then webpart  will show that tasks.

Comment: wait wait ... am I misunderstanding the concept here!!!?  I added an APP called "Tasks" from which I created this Project Task, added some dates and assigned some users to it. It also shows the line who does what... all fine but then User Task is now showing those task.  The one you just suggested, is a separate thing?? When I add a WF task, it does show in user tasks but then it has no connection with the project tasks? I am confused!

Answer (score 0):

Check in the apps category (1st category), there you will find the tasks app and add it into your page. Before that you have create a custom view to display only the logged in users tasks. Otherwise all the user tasks will be visible to all users.

Comment: that is what I done, my friend. First I added new app (tasks) and called it Project Task. Then I created some projects date and assigned to some users... now, I was thinking the "user tasks" webpart would show the individual tasks whoever is logged in as e.g. it would show only my tasks.

Comment: maybe you are referring to [Me] option in filter section?!

Comment: This is my idea behind this all: The main page, should show a small section (whoever is logged in as) of what his/her current project tasks are... and then if they want, they can navigate to the main project page to see everything else.  That is why I used the "user tasks" webpart in thinking it would do that but it does not ... it only shows tasks if you create Workflow tasks - of which I have not much idea about!

Answer (score 0):

Update!

[image]

you can actually hide/show the timeline :)
by this, I could hide it and use it to show only the users tasks.

yeehh, make sense :D

However, I am still confused about the "Workflow Tasks" and the "Project Tasks"